# Adding constraint to an existing table column

Tags: mysql, constraint, check-constraints

I have a table that doesnt have any constraint on them like this

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
   Id int NOT NULL,
   Type varchar(50),
)

insert into SomeTable values (12,'Exchange-Student');
```

Now I know that I can do `alter` into `add constraint` and then `check` if type is of my desired value.
I just dont know how to implement it correctly.

For example lets say that I want it to be restricted to `3` types `'Exchange-Studen'`, `'Independent student'` and `'program Student'`

How would I implement that ?

Comment: That is depending on which versin mysql you have, 8.x you can use CHECK if you have 5.x you have to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger

Comment: I Have the check version so how would I implement it ?

Comment: For older version, a domain table and a foreign key can be used. Its less efficient than a check constraint, but more flexibel since you can extend the domain via SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alter your existing table use

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT `Student_type2` CHECK (Type IN 
('Exchange-Student','Independent student','program Student'))
```

Or ad following to the CREATE TABLE seperated by comma

```
CONSTRAINT `Student_type2` CHECK (Type IN 
('Exchange-Student','Independent student','program Student')
```